# HBase regionserver is aborted and can never be brought up after that

Tags: hadoop, hbase, opentsdb

I used OpenTSDB over HBase (pseudo-distributed Hadoop on virtual box) to send data at very high load (~ 50,000 records / s). The system worked properly for a while but it went down suddenly. I terminated OpenTSDB and HBase. Unfortunately, I could never bring them up again. Every time I tried to run HBase and OpenTSDB, they showed error logs. Here I list the logs:

regionserver:

```
2015-07-01 18:15:30,752 INFO  [sync.3] wal.FSHLog: Slow sync cost: 112 ms, current pipeline: [192.168.56.101:50010]
2015-07-01 18:15:41,277 INFO  [regionserver/node1.vmcluster/192.168.56.101:16201.logRoller] wal.FSHLog: Rolled WAL /hbase/WALs/node1.vmcluster,16201,1435738612093/node1.vmcluster%2C16201%2C1435738612093.default.1435742101122 with entries=3841, filesize=123.61 MB; new WAL /hbase/WALs/node1.vmcluster,16201,1435738612093/node1.vmcluster%2C16201%2C1435738612093.default.1435742141109
2015-07-01 18:15:41,278 INFO  [regionserver/node1.vmcluster/192.168.56.101:16201.logRoller] wal.FSHLog: Archiving hdfs://node1.vmcluster:9000/hbase/WALs/node1.vmcluster,16201,1435738612093/node1.vmcluster%2C16201%2C1435738612093.default.1435742061805 to hdfs://node1.vmcluster:9000/hbase/oldWALs/node1.vmcluster%2C16201%2C1435738612093.default.1435742061805
2015-07-01 18:15:42,249 INFO  [MemStoreFlusher.0] regionserver.HRegion: Started memstore flush for tsdb,,1435740133573.1a692e2668a2b4a71aaf2805f9b00a72., current region memstore size 132.20 MB
2015-07-01 18:15:42,381 INFO  [MemStoreFlusher.1] regionserver.HRegion: Started memstore flush for tsdb,,1435740133573.1a692e2668a2b4a71aaf2805f9b00a72., current region memstore size 133.09 MB
2015-07-01 18:15:42,382 WARN  [MemStoreFlusher.1] regionserver.DefaultMemStore: Snapshot called again without clearing previous. Doing nothing. Another ongoing flush or did we fail last attempt?
2015-07-01 18:15:42,391 FATAL [MemStoreFlusher.0] regionserver.HRegionServer: ABORTING region server node1.vmcluster,16201,1435738612093: Replay of WAL required. Forcing server shutdown
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.DroppedSnapshotException: region: tsdb,,1435740133573.1a692e2668a2b4a71aaf2805f9b00a72.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.internalFlushcache(HRegion.java:2001)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.internalFlushcache(HRegion.java:1772)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.flushcache(HRegion.java:1704)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.MemStoreFlusher.flushRegion(MemStoreFlusher.java:445)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.MemStoreFlusher.flushRegion(MemStoreFlusher.java:407)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.MemStoreFlusher.access$800(MemStoreFlusher.java:69)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.MemStoreFlusher$FlushHandler.run(MemStoreFlusher.java:225)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.CellComparator.getMinimumMidpointArray(CellComparator.java:494)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.CellComparator.getMidpoint(CellComparator.java:448)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFileWriterV2.finishBlock(HFileWriterV2.java:165)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFileWriterV2.checkBlockBoundary(HFileWriterV2.java:146)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFileWriterV2.append(HFileWriterV2.java:263)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFileWriterV3.append(HFileWriterV3.java:87)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.StoreFile$Writer.append(StoreFile.java:932)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.StoreFlusher.performFlush(StoreFlusher.java:121)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.DefaultStoreFlusher.flushSnapshot(DefaultStoreFlusher.java:71)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HStore.flushCache(HStore.java:879)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HStore$StoreFlusherImpl.flushCache(HStore.java:2128)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.internalFlushcache(HRegion.java:1955)
    ... 7 more
2015-07-01 18:15:42,398 FATAL [MemStoreFlusher.0] regionserver.HRegionServer: RegionServer abort: loaded coprocessors are: [org.apache.hadoop.hbase.coprocessor.MultiRowMutationEndpoint]
```

Master:

this is the same to one on regionserver:

```
2015-07-01 18:15:42,596 ERROR [B.defaultRpcServer.handler=15,queue=0,port=16020] master.MasterRpcServices: Region server node1.vmcluster,16201,1435738612093 reported a fatal error:
ABORTING region server node1.vmcluster,16201,1435738612093: Replay of WAL required. Forcing server shutdown
Cause:
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.DroppedSnapshotException: region: tsdb,,1435740133573.1a692e2668a2b4a71aaf2805f9b00a72.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.internalFlushcache(HRegion.java:2001)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.internalFlushcache(HRegion.java:1772)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.flushcache(HRegion.java:1704)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.MemStoreFlusher.flushRegion(MemStoreFlusher.java:445)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.MemStoreFlusher.flushRegion(MemStoreFlusher.java:407)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.MemStoreFlusher.access$800(MemStoreFlusher.java:69)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.MemStoreFlusher$FlushHandler.run(MemStoreFlusher.java:225)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.CellComparator.getMinimumMidpointArray(CellComparator.java:494)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.CellComparator.getMidpoint(CellComparator.java:448)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFileWriterV2.finishBlock(HFileWriterV2.java:165)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFileWriterV2.checkBlockBoundary(HFileWriterV2.java:146)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFileWriterV2.append(HFileWriterV2.java:263)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFileWriterV3.append(HFileWriterV3.java:87)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.StoreFile$Writer.append(StoreFile.java:932)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.StoreFlusher.performFlush(StoreFlusher.java:121)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.DefaultStoreFlusher.flushSnapshot(DefaultStoreFlusher.java:71)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HStore.flushCache(HStore.java:879)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HStore$StoreFlusherImpl.flushCache(HStore.java:2128)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.internalFlushcache(HRegion.java:1955)
    ... 7 more
```

and this:

```
2015-07-01 18:17:16,971 INFO  [node1.vmcluster,16020,1435738420751.splitLogManagerTimeoutMonitor] master.SplitLogManager: total tasks = 1 unassigned = 1 tasks={/hbase/splitWAL/WALs%2Fnode1.vmcluster%2C16201%2C1435738612093-splitting%2Fnode1.vmcluster%252C16201%252C1435738612093..meta.1435738616764.meta=last_update = -1 last_version = -1 cur_worker_name = null status = in_progress incarnation = 0 resubmits = 0 batch = installed = 1 done = 0 error = 0}
2015-07-01 18:17:21,976 INFO  [node1.vmcluster,16020,1435738420751.splitLogManagerTimeoutMonitor] master.SplitLogManager: total tasks = 1 unassigned = 1 tasks={/hbase/splitWAL/WALs%2Fnode1.vmcluster%2C16201%2C1435738612093-splitting%2Fnode1.vmcluster%252C16201%252C1435738612093..meta.1435738616764.meta=last_update = -1 last_version = -1 cur_worker_name = null status = in_progress incarnation = 0 resubmits = 0 batch = installed = 1 done = 0 error = 0}
2015-07-01 18:17:26,979 INFO  [node1.vmcluster,16020,1435738420751.splitLogManagerTimeoutMonitor] master.SplitLogManager: total tasks = 1 unassigned = 1 tasks={/hbase/splitWAL/WALs%2Fnode1.vmcluster%2C16201%2C1435738612093-splitting%2Fnode1.vmcluster%252C16201%252C1435738612093..meta.1435738616764.meta=last_update = -1 last_version = -1 cur_worker_name = null status = in_progress incarnation = 0 resubmits = 0 batch = installed = 1 done = 0 error = 0}
2015-07-01 18:17:31,983 INFO  [node1.vmcluster,16020,1435738420751.splitLogManagerTimeoutMonitor] master.SplitLogManager: total tasks = 1 unassigned = 1 tasks={/hbase/splitWAL/WALs%2Fnode1.vmcluster%2C16201%2C1435738612093-splitting%2Fnode1.vmcluster%252C16201%252C1435738612093..meta.1435738616764.meta=last_update = -1 last_version = -1 cur_worker_name = null status = in_progress incarnation = 0 resubmits = 0 batch = installed = 1 done = 0 error = 0}
2015-07-01 18:17:36,985 INFO  [node1.vmcluster,16020,1435738420751.splitLogManagerTimeoutMonitor] master.SplitLogManager: total tasks = 1 unassigned = 1 tasks={/hbase/splitWAL/WALs%2Fnode1.vmcluster%2C16201%2C1435738612093-splitting%2Fnode1.vmcluster%252C16201%252C1435738612093..meta.1435738616764.meta=last_update = -1 last_version = -1 cur_worker_name = null status = in_progress incarnation = 0 resubmits = 0 batch = installed = 1 done = 0 error = 0}
2015-07-01 18:17:41,992 INFO  [node1.vmcluster,16020,1435738420751.splitLogManagerTimeoutMonitor] master.SplitLogManager: total tasks = 1 unassigned = 1 tasks={/hbase/splitWAL/WALs%2Fnode1.vmcluster%2C16201%2C1435738612093-splitting%2Fnode1.vmcluster%252C16201%252C1435738612093..meta.1435738616764.meta=last_update = -1 last_version = -1 cur_worker_name = null status = in_progress incarnation = 0 resubmits = 0 batch = installed = 1 done = 0 error = 0}
2015-07-01 18:17:45,283 WARN  [CatalogJanitor-node1:16020] master.CatalogJanitor: Failed scan of catalog table
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedException: Failed after attempts=351, exceptions:
Wed Jul 01 18:17:45 KST 2015, null, java.net.SocketTimeoutException: callTimeout=60000, callDuration=68275: row '' on table 'hbase:meta' at region=hbase:meta,,1.1588230740, hostname=node1.vmcluster,16201,1435738612093, seqNum=0

    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCallerWithReadReplicas.throwEnrichedException(RpcRetryingCallerWithReadReplicas.java:264)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:215)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:56)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithoutRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:200)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.call(ClientScanner.java:288)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.nextScanner(ClientScanner.java:267)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.initializeScannerInConstruction(ClientScanner.java:139)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.<init>(ClientScanner.java:134)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.getScanner(HTable.java:823)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.MetaScanner.metaScan(MetaScanner.java:187)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.MetaScanner.metaScan(MetaScanner.java:89)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.CatalogJanitor.getMergedRegionsAndSplitParents(CatalogJanitor.java:169)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.CatalogJanitor.getMergedRegionsAndSplitParents(CatalogJanitor.java:121)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.CatalogJanitor.scan(CatalogJanitor.java:222)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.CatalogJanitor.chore(CatalogJanitor.java:103)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.Chore.run(Chore.java:80)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: callTimeout=60000, callDuration=68275: row '' on table 'hbase:meta' at region=hbase:meta,,1.1588230740, hostname=node1.vmcluster,16201,1435738612093, seqNum=0
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:159)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas$RetryingRPC.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:310)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas$RetryingRPC.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:291)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:739)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:529)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:493)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.setupConnection(RpcClientImpl.java:403)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.setupIOstreams(RpcClientImpl.java:709)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.writeRequest(RpcClientImpl.java:880)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.tracedWriteRequest(RpcClientImpl.java:849)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl.call(RpcClientImpl.java:1173)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient.callBlockingMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:216)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient$BlockingRpcChannelImplementation.callBlockingMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:300)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$BlockingStub.scan(ClientProtos.java:31889)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallable.openScanner(ScannerCallable.java:344)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallable.call(ScannerCallable.java:188)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallable.call(ScannerCallable.java:62)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:126)
    ... 6 more
2015-07-01 18:17:46,995 INFO  [node1.vmcluster,16020,1435738420751.splitLogManagerTimeoutMonitor] master.SplitLogManager: total tasks = 1 unassigned = 1 tasks={/hbase/splitWAL/WALs%2Fnode1.vmcluster%2C16201%2C1435738612093-splitting%2Fnode1.vmcluster%252C16201%252C1435738612093..meta.1435738616764.meta=last_update = -1 last_version = -1 cur_worker_name = null status = in_progress incarnation = 0 resubmits = 0 batch = installed = 1 done = 0 error = 0}
2015-07-01 18:17:52,002 INFO  [node1.vmcluster,16020,1435738420751.splitLogManagerTimeoutMonitor] master.SplitLogManager: total tasks = 1 unassigned = 1 tasks={/hbase/splitWAL/WALs%2Fnode1.vmcluster%2C16201%2C1435738612093-splitting%2Fnode1.vmcluster%252C16201%252C1435738612093..meta.1435738616764.meta=last_update = -1 last_version = -1 cur_worker_name = null status = in_progress incarnation = 0 resubmits = 0 batch = installed = 1 done = 0 error = 0}
2015-07-01 18:17:57,004 INFO  [node1.vmcluster,16020,1435738420751.splitLogManagerTimeoutMonitor] master.SplitLogManager: total tasks = 1 unassigned = 1 tasks={/hbase/splitWAL/WALs%2Fnode1.vmcluster%2C16201%2C1435738612093-splitting%2Fnode1.vmcluster%252C16201%252C1435738612093..meta.1435738616764.meta=last_update = -1 last_version = -1 cur_worker_name = null status = in_progress incarnation = 0 resubmits = 0 batch = installed = 1 done = 0 error = 0}
2015-07-01 18:18:02,006 INFO  [node1.vmcluster,16020,1435738420751.splitLogManagerTimeoutMonitor] master.SplitLogManager: total tasks = 1 unassigned = 1 tasks={/hbase/splitWAL/WALs%2Fnode1.vmcluster%2C16201%2C1435738612093-splitting%2Fnode1.vmcluster%252C16201%252C1435738612093..meta.1435738616764.meta=last_update = -1 last_version = -1 cur_worker_name = null status = in_progress incarnation = 0 resubmits = 0 batch = installed = 1 done = 0 error = 0}
2015-07-01 18:18:07,011 INFO  [node1.vmcluster,16020,1435738420751.splitLogManagerTimeoutMonitor] master.SplitLogManager: total tasks = 1 unassigned = 1 tasks={/hbase/splitWAL/WALs%2Fnode1.vmcluster%2C16201%2C1435738612093-splitting%2Fnode1.vmcluster%252C16201%252C1435738612093..meta.1435738616764.meta=last_update = -1 last_version = -1 cur_worker_name = null status = in_progress incarnation = 0 resubmits = 0 batch = installed = 1 done = 0 error = 0}
```

After that, when I restarted hbase, regionserver showed this error:

```
2015-07-02 09:17:49,151 INFO  [RS_OPEN_REGION-node1:16201-0] regionserver.HRegion: Replaying edits from hdfs://node1.vmcluster:9000/hbase/data/default/tsdb/1a692e2668a2b4a71aaf2805f9b00a72/recovered.edits/0000000000000169657
2015-07-02 09:17:49,343 INFO  [RS_OPEN_REGION-node1:16201-0] regionserver.HRegion: Started memstore flush for tsdb,,1435740133573.1a692e2668a2b4a71aaf2805f9b00a72., current region memstore size 132.20 MB; wal is null, using passed sequenceid=169615
2015-07-02 09:17:49,428 ERROR [RS_OPEN_REGION-node1:16201-0] handler.OpenRegionHandler: Failed open of region=tsdb,,1435740133573.1a692e2668a2b4a71aaf2805f9b00a72., starting to roll back the global memstore size.
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.DroppedSnapshotException: region: tsdb,,1435740133573.1a692e2668a2b4a71aaf2805f9b00a72.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.internalFlushcache(HRegion.java:2001)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.replayRecoveredEdits(HRegion.java:3694)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.replayRecoveredEditsIfAny(HRegion.java:3499)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.initializeRegionStores(HRegion.java:889)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.initializeRegionInternals(HRegion.java:769)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.initialize(HRegion.java:742)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.openHRegion(HRegion.java:4921)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.openHRegion(HRegion.java:4887)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.openHRegion(HRegion.java:4858)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.openHRegion(HRegion.java:4814)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.openHRegion(HRegion.java:4765)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.handler.OpenRegionHandler.openRegion(OpenRegionHandler.java:356)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.handler.OpenRegionHandler.process(OpenRegionHandler.java:126)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.executor.EventHandler.run(EventHandler.java:128)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.CellComparator.getMinimumMidpointArray(CellComparator.java:490)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.CellComparator.getMidpoint(CellComparator.java:448)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFileWriterV2.finishBlock(HFileWriterV2.java:165)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFileWriterV2.checkBlockBoundary(HFileWriterV2.java:146)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFileWriterV2.append(HFileWriterV2.java:263)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFileWriterV3.append(HFileWriterV3.java:87)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.StoreFile$Writer.append(StoreFile.java:932)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.StoreFlusher.performFlush(StoreFlusher.java:121)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.DefaultStoreFlusher.flushSnapshot(DefaultStoreFlusher.java:71)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HStore.flushCache(HStore.java:879)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HStore$StoreFlusherImpl.flushCache(HStore.java:2128)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.internalFlushcache(HRegion.java:1955)
    ... 16 more
2015-07-02 09:17:49,430 INFO  [RS_OPEN_REGION-node1:16201-0] coordination.ZkOpenRegionCoordination: Opening of region {ENCODED => 1a692e2668a2b4a71aaf2805f9b00a72, NAME => 'tsdb,,1435740133573.1a692e2668a2b4a71aaf2805f9b00a72.', STARTKEY => '', ENDKEY => '\x00\x15\x08M|kp\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x01'} failed, transitioning from OPENING to FAILED_OPEN in ZK, expecting version 1
2015-07-02 09:17:49,443 INFO  [PriorityRpcServer.handler=9,queue=1,port=16201] regionserver.RSRpcServices: Open tsdb,,1435740133573.1a692e2668a2b4a71aaf2805f9b00a72.
2015-07-02 09:17:49,458 INFO  [StoreOpener-1a692e2668a2b4a71aaf2805f9b00a72-1] hfile.CacheConfig: blockCache=LruBlockCache{blockCount=3, currentSize=533360, freeSize=509808592, maxSize=510341952, heapSize=533360, minSize=484824864, minFactor=0.95, multiSize=242412432, multiFactor=0.5, singleSize=121206216, singleFactor=0.25}, cacheDataOnRead=true, cacheDataOnWrite=false, cacheIndexesOnWrite=false, cacheBloomsOnWrite=false, cacheEvictOnClose=false, cacheDataCompressed=false, prefetchOnOpen=false
2015-07-02 09:17:49,458 INFO  [StoreOpener-1a692e2668a2b4a71aaf2805f9b00a72-1] compactions.CompactionConfiguration: size [134217728, 9223372036854775807); files [3, 10); ratio 1.200000; off-peak ratio 5.000000; throttle point 2684354560; major period 604800000, major jitter 0.500000, min locality to compact 0.000000
2015-07-02 09:17:49,519 INFO  [RS_OPEN_REGION-node1:16201-2] regionserver.HRegion: Replaying edits from hdfs://node1.vmcluster:9000/hbase/data/default/tsdb/1a692e2668a2b4a71aaf2805f9b00a72/recovered.edits/0000000000000169567
```

**Update**

Today I did the test at very light traffic: 1000 records / sec for 2000 seconds, the problem came again.

Comment: It could be memory related since you are using it in Psuedo-Distributed mode.  Can you up the memory of the VM and provide HBase daemons with more memory?

Comment: @brandon.bell The VM memory was set to 5 GB. My host is 8 GB of RAM so I could not allocate more for the VM. Anyway, what do you mean "provide HBase daemons with more memory" here? Is there anyway I can assign more memory for HBase daemons explicitly? If yes, how much should I give them?

Comment: In hbase-env.sh (usually in /etc/hbase/conf/) you can set HBASE_HEAPSIZE.  Example : `export HBASE_HEAPSIZE=2000`.

Comment: Is there any reason why your running such heavy load on pseudo distributed mode? <br>Have you tried hbck util?

Comment: @AnilGupta My goal is to push time-series data at very high speed. Due to some reasons (maybe cost) our customers might want to install a single server so I tried to use make some performance tests with pseudo-distributed Hadoop.

Comment: i dont think you will get performance advantage via pseudo distributed mode. Try Standalone mode too. 
Also, if you are gonna use a singe node in production. I think, you should also revisit decision to use a NoSql DB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [HBASE-13329](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-13329), a short type overflow has occurred with "short diffIdx = 0" in hbase-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/CellComparator.java. [A patch](https://github.com/apache/hbase/commit/4b934b5734238675e27aaf426e4236e61c57d538) has been available today (2015-07-06). In the patch, HBase developers change the declaration from "short diffIdx = 0" to "int diffIdx = 0".

I did tests with the patch, it worked properly.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you might have disk IO issue. 
HINT: "[sync.3] wal.FSHLog: Slow sync cost". 
Refer to http://search-hadoop.com/m/YGbbn8F9AuR0s42